# Apache2: Is Proxy from https to http secure

Tags: apache-2.4, https, websocket

Im pretty new at all this server stuff, and I have a question regarding the security of the apache proxy.

What I am doing is: I have a websocket server running in non secure mode on port 11221 on the same system (localhost only, but with apache, it's a different application).

In my apache, I created a configuration with a proxy to that server:

```
ServerName websocket.example.com

SSLCertificateFile /path/to/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privkey.pem

ProxyPass / ws://localhost:11221/
ProxyPassReverse / ws://localhost:11221/
```

This combination works flawlessly, I can connect using a **secure** websocket connection to the server (using `wss://websocket.example.com`). And I checked that I can't connect directly to it. `ws://websocket.example.com:11221` will fail with a connection refused (as expected).

My question now is: Is this secure?. I.e. does the connection stay encrypted even after chaning to the websocket protocol? As far as I understood from my research, it does stay encrypted, but I couldn't find a definite answere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL layer is only applied to the connection from client to apache, obviously; that's why you have configured apache after all, isn't it? (Also called "SSL offloading". I usually use pound or haproxy for that, much simpler / smaller than apache if this is all you're using apache for.)

The communication between apache and whatever is listening to port 11221 is necessarily unencrypted; otherwise you would need to install the SLL certificate into the websocket application as well (and also use https:// and not ws://).

That said, if you can't one process to transfer data to another process on the same system (after all you're using `localhost` to communicate), then you have bigger problems. Theoretically someone with the appropriate privileges on the local system can eavesdrop on the communication, but that person could also simply use `strace` on the processe involved to obtain the data.

Comment: So in short: As long as I accept that it's internally unencrypted, it's okay, because the part of the connection between apache and the client stays encrypted.

Comment: Correct, this is the usual setup.